# Ввод чисел в textBox

Tags: c#

Что нужно сделать что бы в  textBox ( VS C#) вводились только числа?

Comment: Как вариант, посмотрите в сторону использования `NumericUpDown`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private void tb_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{    
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Для возможности ввода десятичного разделителя. сразу меняем на правильный системный.

```
    private void e_sum_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if ( !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
        {
            //разделитель еще не стоит
            if (((e.KeyChar == '.') || (e.KeyChar == ',')) && (e_sum.Text.IndexOf(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator[0]) == -1))
                e.KeyChar = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator[0];
            else if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
                e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Если это WinForms

```
private void tb_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
     if (!Regex.IsMatch(e.KeyChar.ToString(), "\\d+"))
          e.Handled = true;
}
```

где tb_KeyPress - обработчик события нажатия клавиши. Код фильтрует все нечисловые нажатия.

Comment: Слишком тяжело использовать регэкспы для задачи, которая решается проще. Пушкой по воробьям.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void tb_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{    
    if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        //запрещаем вводить в textBox1, все кроме числовых значений
        char number = e.KeyChar;

        if (!Char.IsDigit(number))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```