# checkedListBox. Удалить несколько символов, поставить вместо них свои

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно, всё на картинке. Юзверь может ввести три типа номера: +79, 79, 89 с одинаковым телом. Если номер начинается на +79, то нужно убрать три символа, если с 79 или 89, то два, а вместо этого поставить +79.

Как реализовать?

Comment: в комменте потому что не сишарп. у меня так в яваскрипте var transformedInput = inputValue
            .replace(/[^\d+]/g,'')
            .replace(/^89/g,'+79')
            .replace(/^79/g,'+79')
            .replace(/^9/g,'+79')
            .replace(/^(02)([459])/g,'+3752$2') //belarus
            .replace(/^033/g,'+37533')
            .replace(/^044/g,'+37544')
            .replace(/^7([04567])/g,'+77$1') //kazahstan
            ;

Comment: увы, я не пишу на яваскрипте, мне нужно перефразировать в синтаксис шарпа

Comment: так откройте справочник и перепишите 3 реплэйса)

Comment: Посмотрите справку по методам `StartsWith` и `Substring`. Их будет достаточно.

Comment: Сделайте первые символы "+79" статичными и просите пользователя вводить только остальные

Comment: @georgypupkin, а при чем тут `CheckedListBox`? Пользователь куда вводит номер телефона?

Comment: @Андрей
пользователь вводит номер в textbox1 (начало номера может быть разным: +38 (укр), +79 (росс), +375 (бел) ), он может ввести и без '+', алгоритм должен заменить, к примеру, 89xx на +79xx, проверить, если ли этот номер в checklistbox, если есть, то не добавляет, если есть - добавляет. Мне этот алгоритм нужен, чтобы в листбоксе не было таких нюансов:
89xx
+79xx (одинаковые тела номера, но разные начала)

Comment: @Андрей упс, ошибся. если в листбоксе номера нет - добавляет

Comment: @georgypupkin, добавил ответ со своим видением решения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый день!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static string StringRepl(string Str)
        {
            string pattern = @"^(\+79|79|89)[ ]?";
            string Result;
            Regex reg = new Regex(pattern);
            Result = reg.Replace(Str,"+79");           
            return Result;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (1 == 1)
            {
                string StrA;
                StrA = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(StringRepl(StrA));

                if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.E) { break; };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что толку от ответа-*бага*? Телефон "89123897989" переведет как "+79123+79+79+79" - это вы считаете ответом? Могли бы уже и разобраться - для поиска с начала строки используется префикс `^`.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Регулярными выражениями мало пользовался, так что и свои упущения есть.

Comment: как мне RESULT вернуть в обработку нажатия кнопки (pivate void button1_Click)?

Comment: @georgypupkin, простите не совсем понял..   если вам нужен вызов в в обработчике  события по нажатию на кнопку то  тогда вам надо сделать так 
{
    {
        static string StringRepl(string Str)
        {
            string pattern = @"^(\+79|79|89)[ ]?";
            string Result;
            Regex reg = new Regex(pattern);
            Result = reg.Replace(Str, "+79");
            return Result;
        }       

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox2.Text = StringRepl(textBox1.Text);


        }
    }
}

Comment: Спасибо, взял твой алгоритм.

Comment: @ArchiFox есть нюанс, я его выше в комментарии написал. как проверить начало номера уже в условии? Теперь, чтобы определить, какой страны номер. если пользователь ввёл 375xx, то алгоритм должен заюзать этот алгоритм и сделать из введённого значения +375xx.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю лучше сделать как в комменте @Андрей, иначе:

```
string nomertelefona = GetValidString(inputstring);

string GetValidString(string inputstring)
{
    if (inputstring.StartWith("+"))
         inputstring = inputstring.Substring(1);

    return string.Format("+79{0}", inputstring.Substring(2));
}
```

Если понадобиться extension method:

```
public static string GetValidString(this string inputstring) // Метод расширения
    {
        if (inputstring.StartWith("+"))
             inputstring = inputstring.Substring(1);

        return string.Format("+79{0}", inputstring.Substring(2));
    }
```

Comment: Почему два одинаковых кода? Не понял немного.

Comment: Вы можете использовать один из них, второе это extension method

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте ввод телефона по маске, можете поискать готовый контрол (благо их куча) или самостоятельно сделайте что-то типа такого:

[image: Ввод номера телефона]

Выбор кода страны можно сделать, например из выпадающего списка.

Право, вы как будто никогда в жизни ни одной формы не заполняли в приложениях или на сайтах.

У `TextBox` есть полезные свойства для организации такого ввода, такие как `MaxLength`.
Чтобы пользователь мог вводить только цифры, можете воспользоваться, например, [этим ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/36270/218063).
Ну и не забудьте установить этим "кусочкам" нужные значения `TabIndex`

---

Upd. Давно не открывал `WinForms`, оказывается здесь есть стандартный контрол "из коробки" - `MaskedTextBox`, у которого есть свойство `Mask` и даже набор стандартных масок на выбор.
Ниже скрины того, что можно сочинить из `ComboBox` + `MaskedTextBox`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]